# Event for Request denied OpenIdConnect if Client is disabled

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to use oauth2 with OIDC - PKCE with ping identity as authorization server. Everything works fine, but I am having some difficulty when trying to do some error handling.
What OpenIDConnect event should I use if say the application connection in ping was disabled. It seems ping shows the user a error message that client is disabled, with code: ACCESS_FAILED, but I want to catch that event and do some logging on my end too.

I tried following events with no success: OnAccessDenied, OnRemoteFailure, OnMessageReceived.

If someone can please provide me more details on when these events are fired, as the documentation online is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you cannot trap it if the client is disabled at the Authorization Server. Auth server uses "Redirect url" to send back a response. If the client is disabled, then Auth Server cannot retrieve the "Redirect url" to send back a response. This is an expected Oauth2 behaviour.